# extract vba binary from xlsm

Tags: python, excel, xlsm, vba

i've just started to work with excel macros, and i have a few questions :

- i've created an excel macro and assigned it to an xls file (created a button and assign it the macro) . Does this make it an xlsm file ?
- if so, i need assistance to extract the binary from this macro code, in order to use the binary in an external python file. i saw some python scripts that help extracting the binary (such as "olevba.py"\"vba_extract.py"), however when i'm running them, i'm getting the following output:

> python vba_extract.py report.xlsm
>
> File may not be an Excel xlsm macro file: 'report.xlsm'

or :

> "No VBA macros found" (with olevba.py)

please assist

Answer (score 1):

XLSB file (should be located under your doc folders/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Excel/XLSTART)

this file contains the macro binary (code) you wish to extract